Cannot open resource with notebook editor type 'jupyter-notebook' in VScode
I can open.ipynb files locally in vscode, but in remote dev container i have an error:
The editor could not be opened due to an unexpected error: Cannot open resource with notebook editor type 'jupyter-notebook', please check if you have the right extension installed and enabled.
2024-11-18 17:47:06.836 [error] Error: Cannot open resource with notebook editor type 'jupyter-notebook', please check if you have the right extension installed and enabled.
at PW.setInput (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:1358:22719)
More info about all version and container are below.
Local VScode:
Version: 1.96.0-insider (user setup)
Commit: 28f7008e9b2799e3004c48c26fff3d02ec8f13d8
Date: 2024-11-15T05:04:10.294Z
Electron: 32.2.1
ElectronBuildId: 10427718
Chromium: 128.0.6613.186
Node.js: 20.18.0
V8: 12.8.374.38-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19045
Remote dev container:
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:  focal
Linux 0eb4338a3ced 6.1.52-1.el7.3.x86_64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Sep  7 13:28:11 MSK 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Local extensions:
Remote SSH
Identifier ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh
Version 0.115.1
Last Updated 2024-11-15, 14:05:58
Size 5.5 MB
Dev Containers
Identifier ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers
Version 0.388.0
Last Updated 2024-11-15, 14:06:13
Size 7.4 MB
Extensions in Dev Container:
Jupyter
Identifier ms-toolsai.jupyter
Version 2024.10.0
Last Updated 2024-11-18, 10:20:06
Size 19.8 MB
Jupyter Cell Tags
Identifier ms-toolsai.vscode-jupyter-cell-tags
Version 0.1.9
Last Updated 2024-11-18, 09:33:14
Size 455.3 KB
Jupyter Notebook Renderers
Identifier ms-toolsai.jupyter-renderers
Version 1.0.21
Last Updated 2024-11-18, 09:33:14
Size 24.1 MB
Jupyter Slide Show
Identifier ms-toolsai.vscode-jupyter-slideshow
Version 0.1.6
Last Updated 2024-11-18, 09:33:14
Size 427.3 KB
Jupyter Keymap
Identifier ms-toolsai.jupyter-keymap
Version 1.1.2
Last Updated 2024-11-15, 15:27:50
Size 87.2 KB
I also  tried with vscode 1.85.2, 1.95.2 and release, pre-release and older versions of Jupyter extension. So I guess the error in something else then version imcompatible.
